# NDepend Report JustMyCode

Tags: ndepend, cqlinq

I would like to get the Abstractness and Instability of a Solution and ignore third party libraries. I know, I can use JustMyCode in CQLinq, but I want to use the diagram produced by the report. How can I enable JustMyCode for Reports?

Basically I want to ignore third party libraries in Instablity calculation, so that I=0 for the core assemblies of my solution, even if they use third party libraries. But is this a violation against Instability index?

Answer (score 0):

Normally for the Abstractness and Instability diagram in the report the third-party assemblies are ignored isn't it the case?

For the dependency graph you can use this option:

[image: NDepend report settings hide third-party assemblies in the dependency graph]

Comment: I thought about it in the recent minutes and will adjust the question.. I want to ignore the third party libraries in the Instability calculation, so my Core assemblies in my solution should have I=0, even if they used third party libraries. But I guess, then I cannot use the Instability metric as it is?

Comment: ok, you can still write some code query to set calculation formulas the exact way you want, but it won't be plotted automatically on the diagram